# Where to find Castle.MicroKernel.dll

Tags: castle-windsor

This was answered once, but the download site has since changed (apparently) since then. I cannot find Castle.MicroKernel at all. 2.51 can no longer be downloaded and its not in 2.52. or 2.53.

Answer (score 14):

There is no `Castle.MicroKernel.dll` anymore, it was merged into `Castle.Windsor.dll`.

The namespaces are all the same though, i.e. the `Castle.MicroKernel` namespace and all its types now live in `Castle.Windsor.dll`